# Best tool to monitor network connection bandwidth

Tags: windows, networking

I'm looking for a very simple tool to monitor the bandwidth of all my applications.
No need for extra features like traffic spying, I'm just interested by bandwidth.

I already know Wireshark (which is great), but what I'm looking for is more something like  TcpView (great tool from Sysinternals) with current bandwidth indication.

PS: I'm interested by Windows tools only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/), which is great for that and also allows you to limit bandwidth usage so that you can test your app in reduced bandwidth scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, after using it for a couple of hours, I can say that's a great soft, definitely!