# Whats the best way to determine the hardware requirements for an application

Tags: web-applications, hardware, requirements

What methods do you use to determine what kind of hardware you need for a server?

I often find it very hard to predict what kind of hardware you will need for a web based application with a database.

Do you have any good methods or recommendations on how to best pick hardware to use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is sort of the basic question of capacity planning.  You start by defining a *workload model*, which describes what you expect to get in terms of traffic.  This can be as simple as "I expect 20 page hits a minute maximum."

Then you need to think about burst loads.  Failing any other data, you can assume that interarrival times are exponentially distributed, which means that if you have a page request at time *t<sub>0</sub>*, you're as likely to have the next arrival *t<sub>next</sub>* a very short time after *t<sub>0</sub>* as a long time.  (That's a gross oversimplification, but will do for a one-page answer.)

So let's say the average interarrival time is λ.  because the time distribution is exponential, we know that we can approximate the interarrival time distribution with a normal, with one standard deviation (1σ) equal to √λ.  So, we know that

- about 32 percent of the time, two
  pages will be requested less that
  λ- √λ seconds
  apart.
- about 5 percent of the time, two
  pages will be requested less that
  λ- 2√λ seconds
  apart.
- less than 1 percent of the time, two
  pages will be requested less that
  λ- 3√λ seconds
  apart.

Decide what you're willing to accept, and test to make sure your web system can sustain that rate.

Comment: Can you clarify your calculations around interarrival times? At 5 seconds, the 3σ/1% case actually goes negative (-1.7). That doesn't make sense...

Comment: If you have fewer than zero arrivals in a second, how many arrivals are there. Well, zero., you can't have fewer than zero.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what Charlie says, once you have a workload model you can feed this into a simulation of your system to determine the horsepower you need to satisfy that load. There are some tools that can do this sort of simulation:

- [Hyperformix](http://www.hyperformix.com/products/performance-optimizer)
- [SimPy](http://simpy.sourceforge.net/)
- [WikiPedia list of simulation tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_simulation_software)

This stuff isn't easy, and the commercial tools will cost ya.

You could also try looking for a benchmark that's close to your expected load and see what systems give you the performance you're looking for. The [TPC benchmarks](http://www.tpc.org/) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your web app is not a critical business application as you said "a server" and "a database" otherwise you should perhaps look for some means of redundancy ?

At work we have some guidelines about the hardware, and the latest suggestion is that the server should be 64 bits as SharePoint 14 looks like a 64 bits only version.

If you can afford it I would recommend that the SQL server should be 64 bits as most people agree that adding more RAM (above 4 Gb) really pays off.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your web application demands and traffic expectations.

**Very few websites will need more than one reasonable dedicated server within the first months.** And if you do, then you can probably afford to buy more hardware ;)