# How to estimate the internet bandwidth required for running a web application facilitating online transaction?

Tags: java, oracle11g, payment-gateway, bandwidth

I am developing a web application for registration using JSP and Oracle 11g for my organization. The successful registrant will be redirected to online payment gateway where he/she will pay certain amount and will be redirected back to the referring domain. In my application, there are approx 30 numbers of items in the web Form along with the facility to upload user's photograph of maximum 50KB size. The point where I am stuck is how to estimate the internet bandwidth in production environment for handling around say 5000 concurrent users. Hope I have given all the details required for your valuable comments, but should there be any more documentation, please ask me to provide that too. It may be worthy to mention here that we have already 10 MBPS dedicated internet lease line connection for our own server hosting.

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94779/what-is-the-most-accurate-method-of-estimating-peak-bandwidth-requirement-for-a?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but it is not what I want to know. Because, the main issue is during reconciliation. I mean I want to have a rough idea if our existing bandwidth(i.e. 10 MBPS) would be sufficient. I requested comments based on your experience. Also, We may increase the bandwidth upto 30 MBPS. @Falaque.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a good way to estimate this would be to actually do a run-through using the app! Use the app in a browser such as Chrome, with developer tools open. Keep the network tab open - that way you are able to see the size of every request.

From here you can work out how much bandwidth a single user is using per second on average, and then times it by 5000.